# Creating custom composite rendering from Content Editor with minimal visual studio

Tags: sxa, presentation

SITECORE 9.0.2 + SXA 1.7.1

What i am trying to build:

I am trying to create an index/table of contents like [this](https://www.pdfindexgenerator.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/toc_sample.jpg).

[image]

I can have the links pointing to the pages from 'Page List' rendering and a rich text field to hold the part name, as shown in the image.

To make it simpler for content editor, I wanted to create a composite rendering which would consist of 'Rich Text' and 'Page List'

But I am not able to think of a way to achieve the same. Any pointers will be helpful.

I want to achieve this with using the existing SXA functionality to the extent possible.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, my first request is that you include screenshots in the question, rather than relying on a link. You may also be able to achieve something similar by using the Navigation component and adjust the rendering variants to show all the fields you need.

Comment: @MichaelWest: I will take care to avoid links going further. With navigation, i am able to achieve the same as 'Page List'. To provide something as 'Envision the possibilities', again i will have to add a rich text item. Please note 'Envision the possibilities' will not be a link.

Comment: @MichaelWest: Thanks for the input. I used folders to arrange the items and used the navigation to list the children. I will be using jquery/css to disable links coming for folders.

Comment: For someone who comes here: The folder names which are not supposed to be a link can be displayed by another rendering variant. The created variant will have the islink field unchecked. SXA provides the flexibility to assign different rendering variants at different navigation level.

Comment: Are you able to answer your question with screenshots of how it's configured?